# how do solve import error in django project

Tags: django

ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable i have activated the virtualenv on many but yet I can't run the server

Answer (score 0):

When you install Django on your computer all things go fine but when you install a Virtual environment it gets separated from all things.
Just reinstall Django in the virtual environment:

```
pip install Django
```

and then just run the command for testing:

```
python manage.py runsever
```